# Where are the files created by "make modules" when building and compiling the Linux kernel?

Tags: linux, kernel

To build the kernel, I do

1. `make menuconfig`
2. `make`
3. `make modules`

For step3, where do the files go? What's the location for modules? Can I change it by using any env variables?

Comment: Try saying `make -n modules` instead.  That would tell what would happen for the given target.  Since you've probably compiled the modules already, you might want to clean it up first: `make modules clean`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The step 3 will only compile modules. For them to actually go somewhere, you'd have to do `make modules_install`.

As pointed out in comments, `make -n modules_install` will show you where they would go. The exact location depents on the version of the kernel you're compiling, the target directory being `/lib/modules/<kernel_release>`. The version you're building can be found by `make kernelrelease`.